# Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android

I am getting the Comparison method violates its general contract exception with this compareTo method, but I can't track down what is exactly causing the issue.  I am trying to sort files by their extension in a particular way.  Mind you this doesn't happen for all phones, just ones that I don't have access to which makes it harder to test out.

```
public int compareTo(NzbFile another) 
{
    if (this.getFileName() != null && another.getFileName() != null)
    {
        if (this.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".nfo"))
            return -1000;
        else if (another.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".nfo"))
            return 1000;
        else if (this.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".sfv"))
            return -999;
        else if (another.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".sfv"))
            return 1001;
        else if (this.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".srr"))
            return -998;
        else if (another.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".srr"))
            return 1002;
        else if (this.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".nzb"))
            return -997;
        else if (another.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".nzb"))
            return 1003;
        else if (this.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".srt"))
            return -996;
        else if (another.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".srt"))
            return 1004;
        else
            return this.getFileName().compareTo(another.getFileName());
    }
    else if (this.getFileName() != null && another.getFileName() == null)
    {
        return -995;
    }
    else if (this.getFileName() == null && another.getFileName() != null)
    {
        return 1005;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.getSubject().compareTo(another.getSubject());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file names are the same, and both e.g. end in `.nfo`, then this will return that they aren't equal.  I assume that they're meant to be equal.

I strongly suspect that there's a Better Way to Do This.  I'll use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for my example, but it's not strictly necessary.

```
static final List<String> EXTENSIONS = ImmutableList.of("nfo", "sfv", "srr", "nzb", "srt");
final Ordering<String> fileNameOrdering = new Ordering<String>() {
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
    String extA = Files.getFileExtension(a);
    String extB = Files.getFileExtension(b);
    int extAIndex = EXTENSIONS.indexOf(extA);
    int extBIndex = EXTENSIONS.indexOf(extB);
    if ((extAIndex >= 0) == (extBIndex >= 0)) { // if they are both known extensions or both unknown
      return extAIndex - extBIndex;
    } else if (extAIndex < 0) { // a is unknown, b is known
      return -1;
    } else if (extBIndex < 0) { // b is unknown, a is known
      return 1;
    }
    return a.compareTo(b);
  }
}.nullsLast();
return new Ordering<NzbFile>() {
  public int compare(NzbFile a, NzbFile b) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(a.getFileName(), b.getFileName(), fileNameOrdering)
      .compare(a.getSubject(), b.getSubject())
      .result();
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't give me what I want, should have elaborated more.  The reason I gave such high/low numbers in my code was because I wanted files with those extensions to be at the top of the sorted list among other file extensions like .rar

I think the easiest solution is to remove the special files from list before sorting on the rest?

Comment: Higher and lower comparison differences don't make _any_ change, unless you're writing your own sort function or whatever.  According to the contract of `Comparator`, there is no practical difference between returning `-1` and returning `-1000`.

Comment: something is different because my function sorted those special files to the top, and other files like .r01, .r02,etc below those special files where as your function sorts all by their file extension, i.e. sfv and nfo below .r01...

Answer (score 2):

The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.`

This doesn't seem to happen if you compare two files with the same extension. Comparing say `a.nfo` and `b.nfo` returns -1000, both ways round.